# How do I hide an image only within a list item via ID?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I have a list item:

```
<li id="optionCarousel" onclick="toggleTick(this)"><a><img class="tick" id="optionCarousel_Tick" src="/images/tick.png">Carousel</a></li>
```

When I call my method:

```
function toggleTick(element) {
    var elementText = element.id += "_Tick";
    var tickElement = $g(elementText);


    if (tickElement != null) {
        if (tickElement.style.visibility == "visible") {
            tickElement.style.visibility = "hidden";
        }
        else {
            tickElement.style.visibility = "hidden";
        } 
    }
}
```

It hides the entire list item and not just the image which I have passed. Any ideas on how I can hide the image only?

Fiddle [`HERE`](http://jsfiddle.net/subhash9/JDbkj/)

Comment: With the element, pass the id of the image and use that to gather the image and use `hide()` method..

Comment: I can't see how that would even work at all given your `id` selector doesn't start with `#` and therefore wouldn't find anything.

Comment: I meant pass it as a parameter to your function

Comment: What do u mean by id selectors not starting with #??

Comment: "var elementText = element.id += "_Tick";" problem was the += where it should have been just a +..thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
function toggleTick(element) {
    var elementText = element.id += "_Tick";
    var tickElement = $g(elementText);
    tickElement.toggle()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

do something like this:

```
function toggleTick(element) {
    var elementText = element.id += "_Tick";
    var tickElement = document.getElementById(elementText );


    if (tickElement != null) {
        if (tickElement.style.visibility == "visible") {
            tickElement.style.visibility = "hidden";
        }
        else {
            tickElement.style.visibility = "hidden";
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this will be help you

```
$('#optionCarousel').click(function () {
    var tickElement = '#' +$(this).prop('id')+'_Tick';
    $(tickElement).slideToggle();
});
```

Fiddle [`Here`](http://jsfiddle.net/subhash9/JDbkj/2/)